# NGINX error: open_basedir

Tags: nginx

I got this error from my NGINX server when I am running a script in Prestashop.
I think this is something I can solve in the NGINX configuration or something, but I need some help to tell me what to do.

```sh
Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. 
File(/www/wwwroot/panel_ssl_site/../app/etc/env.php) is not within 
the allowed path(s): (/www/wwwroot/panel_ssl_site/) in
/www/wwwroot/panel_ssl_site/bridge_i15GpcsW.php on line 832
```

- How can I solve this?

Thanks,

Petter

Answer (score 0):

## What is PHP open_basedir

> It limits the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified
> directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive *is NOT
> affected* by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
>
> When a script tries to access the file system, for example using
> include, or fopen(), the location of the file is checked. When the
> file is outside the specified directory-tree, PHP will refuse to
> access it. All symbolic links are resolved, so it's not possible to
> avoid this restriction with a symlink. If the file doesn't exist then
> the symlink couldn't be resolved and the filename is compared to (a
> resolved) open_basedir.
>
> open_basedir can affect more than just filesystem functions; for
> example if MySQL is configured to use mysqlnd drivers, LOAD DATA
> INFILE will be affected by open_basedir. Much of the extended
> functionality of PHP uses open_basedir in this way.
>
> The special value . indicates that the working directory of the script
> will be used as the base-directory. This is, however, a little
> dangerous as the working directory of the script can easily be changed
> with chdir().
>
> In httpd.conf, open_basedir can be turned off (e.g. for some virtual
> hosts) the same way as any other configuration directive with
> "php_admin_value open_basedir none".
>
> Under Windows, separate the directories with a semicolon. On all other
> systems, separate the directories with a colon. As an Apache module,
> open_basedir paths from parent directories are now automatically
> inherited.
>
> The restriction specified with open_basedir is a directory name, not a
> prefix.
>
> The default is to allow all files to be opened.

[Reference PHP.NET, 1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

## Conclusion

You have used open_basedir, and you did not update the path.
Additionally, i believe you that this Question should be asked on Superuser, as the evidence tells me that you are not using a Business Related environment.

### php.ini (on Debian 10)

```
; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
; and below.  This directive makes most sense if used in a per-directory
; or per-virtualhost web server configuration file.
; Note: disables the realpath cache
; http://php.net/open-basedir
;open_basedir =
```

That example, from above, is the DEFAULT setting on Debian 10 which is usually also the default on php.net. Which means you have changed it either *manually*. Or what I believe, since the path names included "panel_ssl_site" is that I think you're using an Admin-Panel and this leads to, that this Question goes into OFF-TOPIC. However, every Admin panel should be able to change this setting too, See regarding Reference [StackOverflow to the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths)

Comment: I see nothing here to indicate that this is not a business environment and should go to [su].

Comment: @MichaelHampton /www/wwwroot/panel_ssl_site is the default of [AAPanel](https://www.aapanel.com/index.html) that's why I guess it's not used for a professional hosting

Comment: Oh, a new one I've never heard of! We have a close reason specifically for mass web hosting control panels like cPanel, Plesk etc. so that seems more appropriate.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Nobody stops to learn new things, isnt it so? ;) but Peng58 seems to be gone away since theres no response